# Pyside6 : zoom on graphics with QGraphicsSceneEventWheelevent

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I want to add a zoom fonctionalities on the graphics I post.

I thought that using QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent was a good way to do it but I couldn't make it work, even with some examples.

Do you have some simple examples for this purpose that I can easily use and understand?

> I tried this :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class ImageViewer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Création de la scène et ajout de l'image
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene(self))
        print("3")
        pixmap = QPixmap('ETT_logo.png')
        self.image_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
        self.scene().addItem(self.image_item)
        lbl_img = QLabel(self)
        lbl_img.setGeometry(100 , 10 , 287 , 99)
        lbl_img.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.label = QLabel("No data")
        self.label.setGeometry(100, 200, 100, 100)
        self.setCornerWidget(self.label)
        self.setWindowTitle("QMainWindow WheelEvent")
        self.x = 0

    def wheelEvent(self,event):
        self.x =self.x + event.delta()/120
        print(self.x)
        self.label.setText("Total Steps: "+QStringListModel.number(self.x))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    viewer = ImageViewer()
    viewer.setGeometry(0, 0, 2000, 1200)
    print("1")
    viewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It was supposed to create a window with a label and an image, and then the wheel event should be able to zoom in and out the image.

Comment: Why are you adding another label with the pixmap?

Answer (score 1):

First you should set the views transformation anchor so that when zooming it anchors the zoom around the mouse position with:
`self.setTransformationAnchor(self.ViewportAnchor.AnchorUnderMouse)`

Then inside of the wheelEvent method you can get the direction of the wheel event with `event.angleDelta().y()`. Then based on the negative or positive direction you can set the zoom factor. The zoom factor should be greater than 1 for zooming in, and between 0 and 1 for zooming out.  Then with the zoom factor you can use the `QGraphicsView.scale` method to apply the zoom factor to the current view.

For example:

```
class ImageViewer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene(self))
        self.setTransformationAnchor(self.ViewportAnchor.AnchorUnderMouse)
        pixmap = QPixmap('ETT_logo.png')
        self.image_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
        self.scene().addItem(self.image_item)
        self.setWindowTitle("QMainWindow WheelEvent")

    def wheelEvent(self,event):
        angle = event.angleDelta().y()
        zoomFactor = 1 + (angle/1000)
        self.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor)
```

Comment: I don't understand how the wheelEvent is linked to the image.

Comment: @J-ml9carré  It isn't.  It is linked to the graphicsview/scene

Comment: @J-ml9carré  Did this not answer your question?

Comment: @J-ml9carré We cannot give valid answers if you provide inconsistent code or fragmented information. Please take your time to edit your question and answer to what has been requested in comments. Also, the Graphics View framework is as powerful as it's complex, and it takes time to familiarize it, so please ensure that you've been patiently studied at least [its introduction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/graphicsview.html) in order to understand the relations between items, their parents, their scene, its view(s), and how user events are handled within those contexts.